# How to get the regular expression for starting double quotes?

Tags: vb.net

What will be the regular expression for  "id="fn1"" so as to get only fn1?
I have tried this

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(sLast, "(^\bid=\")[A-Za-z0-9]")
```

This doesnt work. What should I change?

Comment: `^\bid=\"([A-Za-z0-9]*)\"` - https://regex101.com/r/iO4gP3/3

Comment: if I write in codes the following way Dim pattern as string=^\bid=\"([A-Za-z0-9]*)\"    it throws error if I keep it in codes like Dim pattern as string="^\bid=\"([A-Za-z0-9]*)\" " and also if I dont put it in Quotes

Comment: Try `Dim pattern As String = "^(?<=id="")[A-Za-z0-9]*(?="")"`. In VB.NET you escape double quotes by putting an extra quote next to the first. **DO NOTE that putting `^` in the beginning will only check for matches at the beginning of the line**, so if you're trying to match for example HTML tags you must remove `^` from the pattern.

Comment: you have to escape the double quotes `Dim pattern as string = "^\bid=\""([A-Za-z0-9]*)\"""`

Comment: @AlexB. : No, you don't have to escape quotes: http://ideone.com/Epuq1A --- You can even look at the documentation for the `Regex.Escape()` method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What I meant .was that you have to escape double quotes in VB strings so the compiler doesn´t complain. Not in the regex itself. So I tried to say the samething like you. Didn´t see that you already comment it.